# I got error for navigate route, routes provide not found

Tags: flutter, dart

i am getting error when i'll to try navigate page, i've done to provide route on material app properties but error's said provide not found, also i've done to receive navigate provide, so how to fixed?

> let see my code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:navigate_app/category_meals_screen.dart';

class CategoryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final Color color;
  CategoryItem(this.id, this.color, this.title);

  void selectCategory(BuildContext ctx) {
    Navigator.of(ctx)
        .pushNamed('/categories-meals', arguments: {'id': id, 'title': title});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => selectCategory(context),
      child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Text(title),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [color.withOpacity(0.7), color],
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15))),
    );
  }
}
```

> on main.dart

```
//Flutter package
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:navigate_app/category_meals_screen.dart';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:navigate_app/categories_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
          accentColor: Colors.amber,
          canvasColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 254, 229, 1),
          // textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
          //     titleMedium: GoogleFonts.poppins(),
          //     bodyText1: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 51, 1))),
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: '/home',
      routes: {
        '/home': (context) => HomePage(),
        '/categories-meals': (context) => CategoryMealsScreen()
      },
    ));

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: CategoriesScreen());
  }
}
```

in case why this happen?

[image: error's pict]

Answer (score 0):

Please try

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run

Or

Restart android studio and invalidate cache of android studio.